# How to run Karate with a Junit runner without using Maven

Tags: java, karate

We rely heavily on logic in our Junit runner and currently call into it with `mvn test`

The logic mainly consists of

1. Instantiating a `RuntimeHook` and binding it to `Runner.Builder().hook` if an appropriate JVM switch is specified on the command line.
2. Calling `Runner.Builder().clientFactory()` with a mock, again if an appropriate JVM switch is specified on the command line.
3. Last setting minor things like `Runner.Builder().tags` and `Runner.Builder().path`

All of this works perfect today.  Our main gripe however is Maven is slow.

Is there a way to accomplish the above logic and run without the expensive build time of Maven?

Comment: *Maven is slow* How did you determine that it's Maven that's taking the time?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- running more simplistic tests not requiring the logic in the OP we tried running with Maven, then noticed running without it using straight Java commands as noted in this link (eg Karate Cli) were remarkably faster. https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Debug-Server#karate-cli

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mixing a bit of Java code, I think you are going to depend on Maven for build + dependencies. That said, there are ways to ask Maven to dump all JAR dependencies into a text file. For example:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.includeScope=test -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.txt
```

And then you may be able to shape a command that uses the `java` binary directly and you probably already know that [`com.intuit.karate.Main`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Main.java) supports all the extension things. The bad news is I don't think we support things like the custom HTTP Client yet, you can see [this PR](https://github.com/intuit/karate/pull/1404) where someone did this for the `RuntimeHook`. Perhaps you can contribute. Or maybe you have logic in Java code anyway, so calling the Karate `Runner` directly may be the way to go.

I think maybe the solution you will land on is [mvnd](https://github.com/mvndaemon/mvnd) - I haven't used it yet, but I'm hearing very good things on Twitter from some experienced Java folks I follow.

Comment: Thank you for all of the details and ideas Peter.  Ultimately i'm looking for a way to just NOT build if nothing has changed and just run the tests immediately.  I've noticed the Run window in IntelliJ doesn't avoid building, but something is going on with it as run times in standard terminals that take 4.xx seconds, only take 2.xx within it's Run window.  Additionally Visual Studio the commercial version runs MSBuild and has settings to only rebuild when changes are detected, making test execution lightening fast, similar to running Karate.jar on the cmdline.

Comment: @SteveTremblay okay, sorry I don't have more ideas. I would have thought omitting `clean` and only use `test-compile` may do the right thing, guess not

Comment: Interestingly tests don't run when using ```mvn test-compile```.  The fastest approach i've found so far is using ```mvn surefire:test```.  Using that is as fast as IntelliJ and perhaps one of the approaches they use under the hood.  Still not as fast as running Karate.jar.  I'll keeping researching.  ```mvnd``` looks like a good candidate to check out.